# Why are there two #1s of The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl less than a year apart?

Tags: marvel, squirrel-girl

So, there's The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl #1, released in January 2015.

Then there's The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl #1, released in October 2015, by the very same artists.

Why? Why was the numbering reset, so rapidly? Even the name didn't change and, I'm assuming and hoping (as I've yet to read it), neither did the story.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The series was "soft rebooted" to bring it into line with Marvel's newly launched "[All New, All Different](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-New,_All-Different_Marvel)" range of comics (complete with a female Thor and Wolverine and black Spider-Man and Captain America).

The makers used this reboot as an opportunity to make a few changes, updating the artwork, removing some unpopular characters and making Squirrel Girl into a card-carrying member of the Avengers along with a brand new "***issue #1***" banner.

[Overall the changes were quite minor](http://www.newsarama.com/25197-cyborgs-squirrels-time-travel-friendship-promised-in-unbeatable-squirrel-girl-relaunch.html) and unlike other comics in this range, Squirrel Girl's secret identity remains unchanged.

> **Newsarama:** *What can you two tell us about the new arc and new volume of Unbeatable Squirrel Girl?*
>
> **Ryan North:** *It's a new start for Squirrel Girl (which I guess is good seeing as it's got #1 on the title) but it's also a continuation of all that's come before: Tippy-Toe will still be there, Nancy will still be there, Mew will still be there, Chipmunk Hunk and Koi Boi will clearly still be there... but like all the other Marvel books we're jumping ahead eight months, so a lot has changed that we didn't get to see, at least not right away.*
>
> *I don't want to give away too much about our first arc, but I can say it definitely features cyborgs and squirrels and time travel and friendship, and if that doesn't sell you on a comic book, I don't know what will.*
>
> **Nrama:** *Marvel's "All-New" and "All-Different" -- but is Doreen in this new series?*
>
> **Erica Henderson:** *Yes.*
>
> **North:** *There's only one Squirrel Girl! Though I could see an interloper being discovered when her taped-on tail falls off, mid battle. But that's not what happens in our book! You get only the real Squirrel Girl here.*

Comment: @CreationEdge - Their key demo seems to be younger white female readers in the 14-24 bracket, something that comic book companies have always struggled to get interested in *regularly* buying comic serials. [Superman's Girl Friend Lois Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman%27s_Girl_Friend,_Lois_Lane) managed it for a while, as did [She Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-Hulk) but since the early 1990's, it's been a pot of money they really can't tap. My guess is that we'll see more and more 'college girl' and 'teen girl' superhero comics coming out in the next few years.

Comment: I think there's been a discussion on this before, at least in chat with Thad. Character is fine, really, but like Deadpool, belongs more in her own stand-alone stuff instead of affecting larger continuity with her ridiculous silliness (like defeating major villains single-handedly)

Comment: @CreationEdge because Comics Are Serious Business.

Comment: @hobbs Darn tootin!

Comment: Wait there is a female Wolverine? As in X-23 or as in Wolverine was replaced by a woman?

Comment: @Probst - *"X-23 was created to be a weapon and for a time, that's all she was. But with the help of her mentor, LOGAN-the original WOLVERINE-she escaped that dark past. Tragically, Logan has fallen, but Laura will continue in his footsteps as a hero. Recent events have her doing everything in her power to keep those around her alive, as violent forces are hell-bent on mutual destruction. If anyone can stop them, it's Laura. She is the best there is at what she does. **She is THE ALL-NEW WOLVERINE.***" - http://marvel.com/comics/issue/56424/all-new_wolverine_2015_1

Comment: Oh, OK that actually sounds good I'll have to check that out. It makes sense for her to take over as Wolverine but I've never been a big fan of stuff like making a female Thor, that just doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Probst - The aim is to generate controversy, to try to open new markets (e.g. with more gay/female/black characters) and thus sell more magazines.

Comment: That doesn't mean it makes sense to make a female Thor, I mean it's literally based on a male god... I quite like X-23, there are plenty of good female characters for sure and there are a noticeable number of gay and black etc characters too. Diversity really isn't an issue in comics, just off the top of my head I can think of characters of most races and religions. There are even some who are multiple of those, Storm is a huge character and she's female and black. They should have just picked a female Norse god to write about instead of being all weird with Thor.

Comment: @Probst - I refer you to point #1, generate controversy. It's the same reason why they periodically kill Superman.

Comment: I guess... Personally I will not read anything about female Thor because I think it's dumb. I can't be the only one either but then there will be people on the other side who want to read it just to see what it's like even if they didn't typically read Thor. They must have decided more people fit into the later category.

Comment: I'd just like to offer a dissenting opinion in this discussion. I personally **love** the direction Marvel is going. I'm a typical 30-year-old white dude, but I'm getting so bored of yet another white male superhero, yet another nerdy teenage boy suddenly getting powers. Ms. Marvel is great, Squirrel Girl is great, Howard the Duck is great. Comics are supposed to be fun, so to any new readers out there getting into comics because of these books, I say welcome to the club! Really no need be jaded or to dismiss anybody. Plenty of books for everybody.

Answer (score 5):

[As stated on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unbeatable_Squirrel_Girl):

> Starting in May 2015, the Secret Wars crossover storyline affected a
>   number of Marvel comics and character. **Marvel announced in June 2015
>   that, after Secret Wars was complete, they would reboot their entire
>   line as part of a All-New, All-Different Marvel rebranding.** Though
>   The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl was not part of the Secret Wars
>   storyline, the series was set to be rebooted with Squirrel Girl
>   joining an Avengers team. Marvel later named this team the Avengers
>   Idea Mechanics.

Comment: Oh. I did check Wikipedia, but it seems I only read the article on the _character_. Didn't realize there was a seperate article for the series.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to gear my answer to more "novice" comic readers.

### Earth 616

Traditionally, different Marvel comic books take place in the same universe. That means that something that happens in The Avengers book also happens in The X-Men book. For example, if Wolverine dies in The X-Men, you won't see him in The Avengers- unless he's brought back to life, of course! This "main" universe is referred to as **[Earth 616](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-616)**.

### Ultimate

But this can be restrictive to writers- what if they want to reboot a character to have a more modern origin story? They solved this problem by setting their books in a **different universe**- they called this one [**the Ultimate universe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel).

So you've got two **groups** of books set in two different universes. (There are actually many more universes, but these are the main two.)

### Secret Wars

However, this can be confusing for new readers: if you want to start reading Spider-Man, you first have to choose which universe you want to read!

So in 2015, Marvel had a big event called [Secret Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Wars_(2015_comic_book)). This event took place across **every book in every universe**, where different versions of characters met each other and new characters were invented (you might have heard of [Spider-Gwen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Gwen)).

### All New, All Different

At the end of the Secret Wars event, the 616 universe and the Ultimate universe were combined into a single universe- the [All New, All Different universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-New,_All-Different_Marvel), consisting of characters from both universes, as well as some new characters.

As a result of this rebranding, Marvel started a bunch of new series. But they also wanted to keep around some existing characters (like Squirrel Girl) who already had books coming out. **So they started renumbering these books from issue 1 again,** to make it more obvious that they were members of the All New, All Different universe.

### What does this mean for what you should read?

Comic books are generally written in **arcs**, which you can think of as seasons of a TV show. An arc consists of one main storyline that then concludes, and a new arc is started. Arcs usually consist of 3-6 monthly issues, which are usually then collected into trade paperbacks for people who prefer reading them all at once instead of waiting a month between issues.

The renumbering of Squirrel Girl happened **between** the first and second arc. You can think of the first 8 issues as "season 1" of Squirrel Girl. In between season 1 and season 2, Secret Wars happened. Then the numbering starts over at issue 1, and season 2 of Squirrel Girl starts.

In other words, **the renumbering is not a reboot**, but they split it up between "seasons" to make it easier for new readers to get on board, since that was the whole point of Secret Wars to begin with.

So you can read from the very beginning (I'd recommend that, since it's a great book), or you can start at season 2 with the second first issue- they explain pretty much everything you need to know. You don't need to read any Secret Wars books or any other series to understand what's going on in Squirrel Girl.

Comment: The vast complexity (and continual renumbering) is usually a ruse to sell more comics. Also, the periodic killing of characters.

Comment: Richard it wouldn't be so bad if it weren't for the annoying cliché of comic characters  who fail to stay dead. But I'm sure that it always happens for telling a good story and not for selling more.